# What are the details for function argument wp_update_plugin()

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

While looking at [`wp_update_plugin()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_update_plugin/) function.

```
function wp_update_plugin($plugin, $feedback = '') {
    if ( !empty($feedback) )
        add_filter('update_feedback', $feedback);

    include ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
    $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
    return $upgrader->upgrade($plugin);
}
```

Its very hard to know what data type I should send as first argument `$plugin`. Is it the plugin name, file name or object?

Also the second argument `$feedback`. What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument is the plug-in's 'slug'. The plug-in slug is determined by the location of the `.php` file header containing the comment header necessary for plug-ins. (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L234)).

If your main plug-in file might be `~/wp-content/plugins/foo/bar.php`, while your plug-in slug is `foo/bar.php`.

If the `wp-content` dir has a custom name, you can retrieve it using `content_url( $path )`, where `$path` is any trailingslashed single suffix like the plugins directory. Keep in mind that at the end of the function there is a filter, so you better check if something modified it. Then there's `plugins_url( $path, $plugin )` and so on. So you better make sure you got the right path that takes the different possible locations into account.

The second argument is a callback which will be hooked onto `update_feedback` filter. This only appears to be used in `update-core.php` ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php#L569))). I believe this can be used to force flush the output so the user gets some kind of feedback - but I'm not sure where (or if) core does this.

Comment: That filter has also been used here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10407#comment:5